# What commercial/real world apps have been written using PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova

Are there any examples of successful commercial apps written with PhoneGap?  If I were to answer my own question, I would say the Wikipedia app, but that's only for Android.  Isn't the point of PhoneGap apps their ability to run on all mobile platforms?

Comment: Is this the best answer to my question: [link](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/03/27/who-uses-phonegapapache-cordova/)

Comment: That is the exact article I was coming into this question to either post or up vote if someone else had.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bigger point of PhoneGap is that you can write your apps in HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript instead of having to learn Objective-C and Java.

Comment: Most easy to use WEBRTC with phonegap too.

Answer (score 5):

check this out too http://phonegap.com/apps  there is a huge number of phonegap apps out there today

Comment: Not quite what I'd call commercial, but a nice example.

Answer (score 1):

The best one I know about is the one used by freshmen at the University of Oklahoma, called [OUBound](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/oubound/id943063515?mt=8). The app uses PhoneGap and is on Android, Web and iOS.

It was developed by an NYC based design & development studio called [Dom & Tom](http://domandtom.com).